# D3.js sunburst partition rendering incorrectly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm currently in the process of converting the Bilevel Partition sunburst chart [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5944371) from version 3 to version 4 of D3.js. I am using the same data provided by the example and am simply wanting to create the inner pie chart with 10 children, but seem to be running into an issue with the arc sizes. I have an example of my code running with the error at this js fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/bebf54g0/). Here is also the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 350, right: 480, bottom: 350, left: 480},
    radius = Math.min(margin.top, margin.right, margin.bottom, margin.left) - 10;

var hue = d3.scaleOrdinal( d3.schemeCategory10 );

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width",  margin.left + margin.right )
              .attr("height", margin.top + margin.bottom )
            .append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var arc = d3.arc()
    .startAngle( function( d ) 
    {   
        return d.x0; 
    })
    .endAngle( function( d ) 
    { 
        return d.x0 + d.x1; 
    })
    .padAngle( .01 )
    .padRadius( radius / 3 )
    .innerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return radius / 3 * d.depth; 
    })
    .outerRadius( function( d ) 
    { 
        return radius / 3 * (d.depth + 1) - 1; 
    });

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/1093025/raw/490fffd1ae637d3275aa9eaa8b0487147717dd40/flare.json", function(error, root) {

  if( error ) 
  {
    throw error;
  }

  root = d3.hierarchy( root )
           .sum( function ( d )
           {
               return d.size; 
           });

  var partition = d3.partition()
                    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

  var nodes = partition( root )
                .descendants()
                .slice( 1, 11 );


  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data( nodes )
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc )
      .style("fill", function( d ) 
      { 
          return hue(d.data.name); 
      });

});

</script>
```

Instead of using all the data I am rather calling `var nodes = partition( root ).descendants().slice( 1, 11 );` which returns all the nodes that have a depth of 1. This is what the image looks like which is incorrect:

[image]

However, if I change the slice to only use 9 elements instead of 10:

```
var nodes = partition( root ).descendants().slice( 1, 10 );
```

Then the image looks like it's almost correct, with one missing arc.

[image]

This leads me to believe it may be something to do with the arcs, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace

```
.endAngle( function( d,i ) 
    { 
        return d.x0 + d.x1; 
    })
```

by

```
.endAngle( function( d,i ) 
        { 
            return d.x1; 
        })
```